# How can I transfer a file to an iPod without an internet connection?

Tags: itunes, ipod, freeradius

I have a .p12 certificate file I would like to install in an iPod.  How can I transfer this file without having a connection to the internet?  iTunes 12 is installed.  If I need to use an app, that's fine, I just cannot seem to find a way to do this.

Comment: Create a virtual router, connected the iphone to this virtual router, then install the certificate how you normally would on the phone.

Comment: @Ramhound iphone? op has an an **ipod**

Comment: hmm. Why do you need to install a ".p12 certificate file" on an ipod?

Comment: @DavidPostill - virtually the same.

Comment: @Ramhound Really? Please tell me how I can make phone calls from my IPod, or browse the internet. More to the point why do I need a certificate on my iPod?

Comment: @DavidPostill - trying to connect it to wifi at a location that uses 802.1x for connection.  The iPod I have here lets you browse the net and everything.

Comment: Hmm. My ipod only plays music. I suppose it's an old model (Apple iPod classic (160GB))

Comment: @DavidPostill - I was thinking more of the ipod touch being virtually identical to the iphone.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the iPod is running IOS you should be able to use the iPhone configurator [from the app store](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/apple-configurator/id434433123?mt=12). It's usually used for mass configuring iPads or iPhones, but will likely work with an iPod too.

If you click <kbd>Prepare</kbd> > <kbd>Setup</kbd> > <kbd>Certificates</kbd> > <kbd>Configure Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Configure</kbd>

You can then choose PKCS1 or PKCS12 formatted certificates to install.

If you navigate back to the <kbd>Settings</kbd> tab on the main screen, you should be able to install the profiles with <kbd>Install Profiles...</kbd> or <kbd>Prepare</kbd>.

Installation is done with a USB cable, which satisfies your no internet requirement.